# Pass a string and compare it to a list

Tags: string

I am passsing an argument through robot framework.  The argument is a string. "Detroit".
I want the code to break down that string to "D", "De", "Det", "Detr", "Detro","Detroi", and "Detroit".  Of course if another string is entered, say "Flint" it would only break it down into the 5 elements. F, Fl, Fli, Flin, Flint.

(Pseudo Code)

```
def checkCity (self, x):
     (take x which is the string, and make it a list of elements containing the letters as above).
     (Then take each element and check it against data provided by the device(using a loop for each iteration)
     (Once any of the elements are matched to the data, return another function that acts as a key press)
```

I'm familiar enough with python (and programming) in general to have the theory, just don't know how to code it.

Comment: This should be a trivial loop... can you show what you've tried already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the programming language that you are using but I will help out as much as I can.

For breaking down the string, you could use a `while` loop or a `for` loop, whichever you prefer. The ending condition being the length of the string that you put into the second parameter. In the loop, you can use `substring` method to break down the string and store each element into an array list.

Then for checking if any of the elements are matched, you would (as you have said) use a loop for each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can access individual parts of a string by using

```
string[5:7]
```

That would give the 5th and 6th characters

This function in python will return a list like the one you want

```
def toSubLists(string):
    sublists = []
    for i in range(1, len(string)+1):
        sublists.append(string[0:i])
    return sublists
```